# Thymeleaf Conditional Statement

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

When using Thymeleaf, I am trying to show a certain image conditionally.
This works properly

```
<img th:if="*{ score &lt; 20 and score &gt; 0}" src="images/Fast-Track-No1.jpg" th:href="@{/images/Fast-Track-No1.jpg}"  style = "width: 450px;" alt=""/>
```

However, this does not work.. Only changing the &gt to &ge

```
<img th:if="*{ score &lt; 20 and score &ge; 0}" src="images/Fast-Track-No1.jpg" th:href="@{/images/Fast-Track-No1.jpg}"  style = "width: 450px;" alt=""/>
```

I receive an error that states "missing expected character '&'"

All I did was change the &gt to &ge..

I followed the documentation here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#comparators-and-equality

I have done the check with ge first and there is no difference. I have also tried as the doc shows without the ampersand as such

```
*{score} ge; 0"
```

and it still fails and throws errors.  According to my pom.xml file I am using ThymeLeaf 2.1.2.RELEASE.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Jim on the Thymeleaf Forum.. There is no xml Entity for >= or <=.
This fixed it.

```
<img th:if="*{ score &lt; 20 and score &gt;= 0}" src="images/Fast-Track-No1.jpg" th:href="@{/images/Fast-Track-No1.jpg}"  style = "width: 450px;" alt=""/>
```